# using pydub to convert audio from .au to .wav

Tags: python, pydub

In this code m getting an error as follows:

```
import os

from pydub import AudioSegment

song = AudioSegment.from_file('C:/Users/Rishabh/Desktop/metal.00000.au','au')
song.export(path[:-3]+"wav",format='wav')
```

I am getting the following error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Well, as your error is saying, the file cannot be found. Check if you path and filename

Comment: Another thing to check is whether the ffmpeg binary is in the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is more than two and a half years old by now, and hopefully you've not been stuck with this problem since then. But maybe someone else fumbles into the same problem (such as me...)

As Jiaaro mentions, check the ffmpeg path. Also, make sure you've installed ffmpeg in your environment. Here is an old thread I found on github with some more detail in checking ffmpeg availability, also with answers from Jiaaro:
https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/5#issuecomment-8397126

Myself, I'm running anaconda on windows 10 and needed to install pydub and ffmpeg separately in my conda environment for pydub to work.
If your goal is to simply convert from au to wav (without any other programmatic context) you can execute ffmpeg in your environment from the terminal with the -i flag. Like so:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\Rishabh\Desktop\metal.00000.au" "C:\Users\Rishabh\Desktop\metal.00000.wav"
```